# why pie chart is showing value for only one field?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, charts

I am trying to use a pie chart and I expect 2 regions get displayed on it. But for my following code, only the last one is shown.

```
Code behind:

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("status");
        dt.Columns.Add("count");

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["status"] = "safe";
        dr["count"] = loadChart("safe");

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr["status"] = "unsafe";
       dr["count"] = loadChart("unsafe");

        dr = dt.NewRow();

       dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        Chart1.DataSource = dt;

        Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "status";
        Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "count";

        Chart1.DataBind();
    }
```

**Mark up:**

```
 <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
        <series>
            <asp:Series ChartType="Pie" Name="Series1">
            </asp:Series>

        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

**output:**

[image]

I want to see the safe portion also. I have value for it.how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting values in the same row twice:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["status"] = "safe";
dr["count"] = loadChart("safe");
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
//still in the same row
dr["status"] = "unsafe";
dr["count"] = loadChart("unsafe");
dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

you should create new row and then set second values:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["status"] = "safe";
dr["count"] = loadChart("safe");
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
//new row creation
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["status"] = "unsafe";
dr["count"] = loadChart("unsafe");    
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: I don't know, don't use this control. Here you have some posts and documentation: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11001